# Can you complete the expression $2 \underline{ }\, \underline{ }\, \underline{ } \,\underline{ } 5 = 2015$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> Can you complete the expression
>
> $2 \underline{ } \, \underline{ }\, \underline{ } \, \underline{ } 5 = 2015$
>
> and make it correct by replacing two underscores with a selection of the operational symbols $+, - , /, \times$ and the other two underscores with digits $0,1,\ldots,9$?

I have been working on this problem for quite a while now where my main strategy has simply been trial and error. However, I still can't seem to find a combination of operational symbols and digits where the result gives me 2015. If this is in fact not possible I would greatly appreciate an explanation and if it is possible, I would greatly appreciate an explanation of how you were able to solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: $ 2 \cdot 9\cdot 95=1710<2015$ so I don't see how this is possible using exactly two operations and two digits.

Comment: Maybe something like 2{10^2(+3)}x5 derived with the gauss law instead

Comment: Maybe this is looking for cheating answers, like writing the `1` in `2010+5` as a rotated minus sign?

Comment: What if we relax the condition by saying that $2$ and $5$ can be anywhere (but still with two operators)?

Comment: Do they have to be numbers? If we use + as text concatenation (as in SQL, for example) then 2+01+5=2015.

Comment: Considering the question asks, "Can you..." I think it would be proper to just say, "No."

Comment: I think the question challenges about if you understand easily how to find the domain of 2 _ _ _ _ 5 based on the restriction set. It's often easy when there's not these restrictions to find a matching equation, but being able to calculate the limit of 1710 is helpful to avoid trying all the possibilities, and to answer "No." Other answers don't respect the restrictions.

Comment: Should the question be taken at face value, or is it possible it's playing a word game?  For example the words `with a selection of`, with a loose enough interpretation, could include the option to select nothing, eg: `20__15`

Comment: @BrianVandenberg in some languages like Ada, Java, Perl and Ruby, one can use _ as a digit separator in an integer literal. At least in Java and Perl, the _ can be placed anywhere between two digits and 2_0_15 is equal to 2015 numerically.

Comment: @achillehui Since it's labeled with number theory & recreational math I'm inclined to think it's a strictly math question.  The wiggle room I was asking about is things like: is the number system base 10 (eg, your base 8 answer below)?  Are we limited to elementary algebra rules for the given symbols (eg, different types of algebras)?  Is selecting nothing a valid selection from the set of symbols?  ... etc

Comment: I suppose you could be absurd about it and define the meaning of the symbols since those definitions are only implied, but that's probably not what they're looking for.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is not possible, the largest number we can make using **two** operations and **two** digits is given by
$$ 2 \cdot 9\cdot 95=1710<2015$$
so this problem has no solution stated as such. Of course if you relax the condition 2 operations-2 digits then, as proposed by 5xum (who proposed 2010+5), it is much easier.

Comment: a different way of relaxing would be to include "^" (power) into the operations allowing for much greater numbers. However, I havent found a solution including this

Comment: @Bort We have ``2^10+5=1029<2015<2043=2^11-5`` and ``29+4^5=1053<2015<3145=20+5^5`` so it seems also impossible when allowing ``^``

Comment: Can confirm this, wrote some code to do the work: http://pastebin.com/DJP8U9iF

Comment: @surb : okay i should have been wordier..  This the exact same argumentation I so eloquently phrased with "havent found a solution". But thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @simonzack Could you add which language this is? (looks like python to me, but then I would guess some includes are missing)

Comment: @Bort It is indeed python, I have left out `import itertools`.

Answer (score 43):

Exactly two underscores must be occupied by operators. Furthermore, no two operators can be placed adjacently, as this would be syntactically meaningless. Hence, there are only three possible arrangements of digit and operator positions:

- $2$ # @ # @ $5$
- $2$ @ # @ # $5$
- $2$ @ # # @ $5$

For each case, we choose the digits and operators that give *the largest possible output*, to see if it actually possible to reach the required *neighborhood* of values.

By inspection, I think it is fairly obvious that for each of the three cases above, filling the blanks with 9's and multiplication in the indicated positions (# for number, @ for operator) yields the largest possible output for each case:

- $2 9 \times 9 \times 5 = 1305$
- $2 \times 9 \times 9 5 = 1710$
- $2 \times 9 9 \times 5 = 990$

Any other digits or operators *decrease* the output, hence it is not possible to reach the neighborhood of $2015$, and therefore (I'm quite sure) the task is not possible.

Comment: `no two operators can be placed adjacently, as this would be syntactically meaningless` It is meaningless, but still possible. See my answer

Answer (score 39):

No where in the puzzle forces us to interpret the digits as decimal numbers.
In base $8$, we have:
$$21 \times +75 = 2015$$

Comment: Well it does say "digits 0, 1, ... 9", that implies decimal.

Comment: @Cimbali, not really. It means if you ever use digit $8$ or $9$, then you cannot interpret the strings as octals.

Comment: It implies decimal, but it's not overtly stated.  You could choose a base higher than 10 with the obvious consequence that you'd be restricted to using only the 1st 10 digits of that base.

Answer (score 23):

The puzzle does not restrict the operations to binary, so using `+` as a unary operator opens up even more possibilities and allows to reach higher numbers. It seemed promising at first, but sadly none of the possibilities is 2015. Here's a table:

$$ 2\mathrm{X} \times +\mathrm{Y}5$$

[image]

Comment: good out-of-the-box thinking! One should consider $2XY\times +5$ and $2\times XY5$  as well. The latter gives multiples of $10$, the former requires $2XY=402$ though

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen True, but the largest it can get is $2 \times +995 = 1990$

Answer (score 5):

## Brute force solution

I originally wrote the solution for 5 slots, with only 4 slots this approach proves that only two solution candidates appear: `2010+5` and `2020-5`. Obviously these don't match the criterium so it is proved that no solution exists. For illustration I will hereby show how I found the solution for when there are 5 slots.

### Approach

It can easily be seen that there there are just a limited number of possibilities here. A simple upper bound can be found by considering that each slot can be occupied by 14 different characters, and there are 5 slots. As such we can simply try roughly half a million possibilities (14^5 to be exact) and evaluate the solution.

### Matlab code

```
v = ['0':'9' '+' '-' '*' '/'];

results = [];
for a=v
    for b=v
        for c=v
            for d=v
                for e=v
                    x = false;
                    s = ['x = 2' a b c d e '5 == 2015;'];
                    try 
                        eval(s);
                    catch
                    end
                    if x
                        results = [results; s];
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

### Results

```
x = 2000+15 == 2015;
x = 2010+05 == 2015;
x = 2010++5 == 2015;
x = 2010--5 == 2015;
x = 2020+-5 == 2015;
x = 2020-05 == 2015;
x = 2020-+5 == 2015;
x = 2030-15 == 2015;
x = 2040-25 == 2015;
x = 2050-35 == 2015;
x = 2060-45 == 2015;
x = 2070-55 == 2015;
x = 2080-65 == 2015;
x = 2090-75 == 2015;
x = 20+1995 == 2015;
x = 2100-85 == 2015;
x = 2110-95 == 2015;
```

### Conclusion

Most combinations do not meet the restriction of having exactly 2 operators, but some do. My personal favorite which I would personally consider to be the answer:

```
2010--5 == 2015
```

Comment: There aren't five slots though, there are only four.

Comment: Cue someone complaining about `eval` in 5..... 4..... 3.....

Comment: @hvd Incredible, I updated the answer slightly to match the question. I just ran the code for 4 slots but unfortunately no solution exists.

Comment: @immibis Perhaps I can state premptively that I am aware that `eval` should be avoided in most situations, but that I think this is a proper usage of `eval`.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin False. I modified your code for the 4 slot case, and you get 2010+5 and 2020-5. Granted this isn't a solution to the original problem, but it is a solution to the one you present, with relaxed conditions. Still +1. I like this code.

Answer (score 4):

As shown by the other answers, this problem is impossible with two operators and two regular digits. So we'll have to take liberties:

Taking the liberty of an extra possible operator gets us closer, as shown by `Surb`'s comment to his own answer. If we take another operator than what he suggests, and include the factorial operator, then we get very close:

$$2 \cdot 7! / 5 = 2016$$

But there is another option if we don't restrict ourselves to base 10. If we can write either the number 1000 or 1010 with 2 'digits', then we can solve this problem quite easily. This requires a base of at least 32, since x^2 > 1010. Fortunately, base 32 is fairly straightforward if you're used to hexadecimal notation. It only extends to V, which is equal to 31 in base 10.

$$1000 = 31 \cdot 32 + 8 = V8$$

Therefore, if we accept base 32 as an allowed relaxation to your rule:

$$2 \cdot V8 + 5 = 2015$$

Comment: While this is an interesting attempt, I believe there is one fundamental flaw. We can't pick and choose what to consider base 10 and what to consider base 32. On the left hand side you are computing base 32, so the right hand side would need to be base 32 as well but $2*V8+5$ is significantly less than $2015$ base 32(which is $2*32^3+32+5$ in base 10.)

Comment: That is a very valid point. It then depends whether you want, in base 32, the value $2015$ or the value $1UV$